# scala how to use pattern matching with inheriance and templated class

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

We use at our company a data structure that looks like that:

```scala
trait Resource

case class templatedResource[T](t: T) extends Resource

case class BParameter()
case class CParameter()

object B {
  type Resource = templatedResource[BParameter]
}

object C {
  type Resource = templatedResource[CParameter]
}
```

At some point, given some unknown `Resource`s we want to use pattern matching to determine their inner types and launch some different processings.

But due to Type Erasure, simple pattern matching doesn't work. So we have tried to use `TypeTags`, but without success :

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Service {

  def process(resource: Resource)(implicit tag: WeakTypeTag[Resource]) = {
    (tag.tpe, resource) match {
      case (t, b: B.Resource) if t =:= typeOf[B.Resource] =>
        println("b !!")
      case (t, c: C.Resource) if t =:= typeOf[C.Resource] => 
        println("c !!")
      case _ => 
          throw new IllegalStateException(s"Unexpected resource type")
    }
  }
}

val bParam = BParameter()
val bResource: B.Resource = templatedResource(bParam)

Service.process(bResource)
//  throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected resource type
//         at Service$.process(<console>:26)
```

It seems that the `t =:= typeOf[B.Resource]` are always false because `t` only knows the `Resource` trait ( `t =:= typeOf[Resource]` ) and not the concrete implementation.

How can I get this pattern matching to work ?

Comment: If you need to check which subclass do you have at runtime you have a design error. Either make resource a `sealed trait` so you can use structural pattern matching instead, or create a good abstraction that defines the contract all resources have to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your erasing type parameters in some new type. Type alias is not a new type, is just an additional name for the current type.

You can do something like this:

```
trait Resource

class templatedResource[T](t: T) extends Resource

case class BParameter()
case class CParameter()

object B {
  case class Resource(val b: BParameter) extends templatedResource[BParameter](b)
}

object C {
  type Resource = templatedResource[CParameter]
}

def process(r: Resource) = {
  r match {
    case a: B.Resource => true
  }
}

process(B.Resource(BParameter()))
```

If you need to preserve the creation syntax `val bResource: B.Resource = templatedResource(bParam)` in order to eliminate boilerplate for end-user - you should define the function with such creation. To eliminate implementation
boilerplate of the function - you can use macro or something like shapeless, I guess.

Comment: That would be a good solution, yes.
Unfortunately, we will have no time to such refactoring, so I did something ugly with @unchecked pattern matching, adding more ugly patch on this already flawed design :/

Comment: @JRUtily Yeah, this is a common time/quality trade-off. I wish you will have time for such refactoring soon :)